# Add style to running OpenMapTiles server

Tags: docker, dictionary, openmaptiles, openmap

I'm using the OpenMapTiles Docker image on a VPS, and would like to use a custom map style created with Maputnik. I've already gone through the "setup" process, so when I go to the server's address, I see a list of the styles currently available. I don't see any option to add a new style, so I was wondering if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the json style file to the default folder and restart the OpenMapTiles server.

Edit: restart might not be the best option. Try a full stop and start then.